# python - Aggregating time stamps to see how many I have in 10 ­minutes time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time, series

I have a list of dates in a jason file, and like to aggregate them to see how many I have in 10 ­minutes time intervals.. I think time series in Pandas is what I should look for, but I am confused! Any idea?

[more details]
when I load the json file using  pd.read_json; I get only one column; which has about 10,000 rows. each row is a pandas.tslib.Timestamp such as "1970-01-01 20:12:16". 
Ideally, I like to group these Timestamps into 10 ­minutes time intervals; to see how many Timestamps I have in each interval and draw a bar chart (histogram).

Comment: well, how are the times formatted? what have you tried so far? you have to give us more to work with.

Comment: Please take a look here to learn how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: just added more details..

Answer (score 5):

You can do this doing [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

First index on the timestamp column, if you have not already done so:

```
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

Add a numeric column (you need something for resampling to aggregate):

```
df['count'] = 1
```

And finally resample as needed:

```
df.resample('10T', how='sum')
```

Answer (score 3):

I use truncation to do this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

ts = [dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(minutes = random.randint(1000)) for _ in range(1000)] 
df = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns = ['ts'])

def truncate(t):
    return dt.datetime(month = t.month, day = t.day, year = t.year, hour = t.hour, minute = (55 / 10) * 10)

df.ts.map(truncate).value_counts()
```

will give you the counts per 10 minutes

```
2016-02-20 00:50:00    79
2016-02-19 23:50:00    75
2016-02-20 08:50:00    72
2016-02-19 21:50:00    70
...
```

**EDIT**:

The method by A. Leistra is much better, I learned something as well. It works from the setup above:

```
df.set_index('ts', inplace = True)
df['count'] = 1
df.resample('10T', how = sum).head()

count | ts
--- | ---   
2016-02-19 21:00:00     5
2016-02-19 21:10:00     11
2016-02-19 21:20:00     17
2016-02-19 21:30:00     13
2016-02-19 21:40:00     11
```